# How can I find out the version of MSYS2 from its bash shell

Tags: msys2

I would like to find out which version of MSYS2 is currently running, from within its bash shell.

For example, is there a command, similar to Windows "ver", or or a specific package that denotes the entire MSYS2 installation?

In case it matters, I am using the MSYS subsystem of MSYS2.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ cat /proc/version

MINGW32_NT-10.0-22000 version 3.3.4-341.x86_64 (runneradmin@fv-az448-481) (gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC) ) 2022-02-15 17:24 UTC
```

or

```
$ uname -a

MINGW32_NT-10.0-22000 LAPTOP-FJNTRVPC 3.3.4-341.x86_64 2022-02-15 17:24 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

Answer (score 2):

MSYS2 is basically just a collection of packages installed on your computer, managed by a package manager, which is itself a package.  There is no overall version number.  You can find out the versions of all your packages by running:

```
pacman -Q
```

Comment: hi David.  Unfortunately, this isn't true.  There is actually an overall version number.  See @John's answer.

Comment: That is probably just the version number of the msys2-runtime package, which is just the package that provides POSIX support.  Other packages can get updates without that number changing.

Answer (score 0):

If they msys is installed as the part of Ruby, then one can do

```
C:\>ridk exec pacman -Q
autoconf 2.69-5
autogen 5.18.16-1
automake-wrapper 11-1
automake1.10 1.10.3-4
automake1.11 1.11.6-4
automake1.12 1.12.6-4
automake1.13 1.13.4-5
automake1.14 1.14.1-4
automake1.15 1.15.1-2
automake1.16 1.16.2-2
automake1.6 1.6.3-3
automake1.7 1.7.9-3
automake1.8 1.8.5-4
automake1.9 1.9.6-3
base 2020.05-2
bash 4.4.023-2
bash-completion 2.10-1
brotli 1.0.7-4
bsdtar 3.4.3-1
bzip2 1.0.8-2
ca-certificates 20190110-1
coreutils 8.32-1
curl 7.71.1-1
dash 0.5.11.1-2
db 5.3.28-3
diffutils 3.7-1
file 5.39-1
filesystem 2020.02-7
findutils 4.7.0-1
gawk 5.1.0-1
gcc-libs 9.3.0-1
gdbm 1.18.1-3
getent 2.18.90-2
gettext 0.19.8.1-1
glib2 2.54.3-3
gmp 6.2.0-1
gnupg 2.2.23-1
grep 3.0-2
gzip 1.10-1
heimdal-libs 7.7.0-2
icu 67.1-1
inetutils 1.9.4-2
info 6.7-3
less 551-1
libargp 20110921-2
libasprintf 0.19.8.1-1
libassuan 2.5.3-1
libatomic_ops 7.6.10-1
libbz2 1.0.8-2
libcrypt 2.1-2
libcurl 7.71.1-1
libdb 5.3.28-3
libedit 20191231_3.1-1
libexpat 2.2.9-1
libffi 3.3-1
libgc 8.0.4-1
libgcrypt 1.8.6-1
libgdbm 1.18.1-3
libgettextpo 0.19.8.1-1
libgnutls 3.6.14-1
libgpg-error 1.38-1
libgpgme 1.14.0-2
libguile 2.2.7-1
libhogweed 3.6-1
libiconv 1.16-2
libidn2 2.3.0-1
libintl 0.19.8.1-1
libksba 1.4.0-1
libltdl 2.4.6-9
liblz4 1.9.2-1
liblzma 5.2.5-1
libmetalink 0.1.3-3
libnettle 3.6-1
libnghttp2 1.41.0-1
libnpth 1.6-1
libopenssl 1.1.1.g-3
libp11-kit 0.23.20-2
libpcre 8.44-1
libpcre2_8 10.35-1
libpsl 0.21.0-1
libreadline 8.0.004-1
libsqlite 3.33.0-2
libssh2 1.9.0-1
libtasn1 4.16.0-1
libtool 2.4.6-9
libunistring 0.9.10-1
libutil-linux 2.35.2-1
libxml2 2.9.10-6
libxslt 1.1.34-3
libzstd 1.4.5-2
m4 1.4.18-2
make 4.3-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils 2.35.1-2
mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git 8.0.0.6001.98dad1fe-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-expat 2.2.9-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc 10.2.0-3
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs 10.2.0-3
mingw-w64-x86_64-gettext 0.19.8.1-9
mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp 6.2.0-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git 8.0.0.6001.98dad1fe-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-isl 0.22.1-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv 1.16-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git 8.0.0.6001.98dad1fe-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git 8.0.0.6001.98dad1fe-3
mingw-w64-x86_64-make 4.3-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc 1.2.0-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr 4.1.0-2
mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config 0.29.2-2
mingw-w64-x86_64-readline 8.0.004-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3 3.33.0-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl 8.6.10-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-termcap 1.3.1-6
mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git 8.0.0.6001.98dad1fe-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest 6.4-3
mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git 8.0.0.6001.98dad1fe-3
mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib 1.2.11-7
mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd 1.4.5-1
mintty 1~3.4.0-1
mpfr 4.1.0-1
msys2-keyring r21.b39fb11-1
msys2-launcher 1.0-1
msys2-runtime 3.1.7-2
ncurses 6.2-1
nettle 3.6-1
openssl 1.1.1.g-3
p11-kit 0.23.20-2
pacman 5.2.2-4
pacman-contrib 1.3.0-1
pacman-mirrors 20200329-1
patch 2.7.6-1
perl 5.32.0-2
pinentry 1.1.0-2
pkg-config 0.29.2-1
rebase 4.4.4-2
sed 4.8-1
tar 1.32-1
tcl 8.6.10-1
texinfo 6.7-3
texinfo-tex 6.7-3
tftp-hpa 5.2-3
time 1.9-1
tzcode 2020a-1
util-linux 2.35.2-1
wget 1.20.3-1
which 2.21-2
xz 5.2.5-1
zlib 1.2.11-1
zstd 1.4.5-2
```

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer posted almost 2 years ago? Are you saying that specifically the package `msys2-runtime` is the one of interest here? or something else?